# Nginx consumes 100% RAM

Tags: nginx

On busy server Nginx consumes 100% RAM. Where I should start to look for the  problem and maybe there is a way to see detail memory usage?

nginx version: nginx/1.17.3

Busy cache:

```
proxy_cache_path /mnt/disk2/cfs levels=1:2 keys_zone=cfs:50m max_size=270g inactive=3h use_temp_path=off;
```

Cache is also on other servers and has no impact on memory usage.

```
free -h 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        7.0G        262M        4.8M        553M        546M
Swap:          2.0G         41M        2.0G
```

```
swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/xvdb1                              partition       2096444 42736   -2
```

```
24580:   nginx: worker process                   
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode  Mapping
000055f7200af000    1160     520       0 r-x-- nginx
000055f7200af000       0       0       0 r-x-- nginx
000055f7203d0000       8       8       8 r---- nginx
000055f7203d0000       0       0       0 r---- nginx
000055f7203d2000     132      84      72 rw--- nginx
000055f7203d2000       0       0       0 rw--- nginx
000055f7203f3000     124      20      20 rw---   [ anon ]
000055f7203f3000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
000055f7213f3000    4412    3932    3932 rw---   [ anon ]
000055f7213f3000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
000055f721842000 3129980 3128776 3128776 rw---   [ anon ]
000055f721842000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b212d5000   21488   16256   16256 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b212d5000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b227d1000      28      28       0 r-x-- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b227d1000       0       0       0 r-x-- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b227d8000    2044       0       0 ----- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b227d8000       0       0       0 ----- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b229d7000       4       0       0 r---- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b229d7000       0       0       0 r---- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b229d8000       4       0       0 rw--- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b229d8000       0       0       0 rw--- librt-2.27.so
00007f1b229d9000     240       0       0 r-x-- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b229d9000       0       0       0 r-x-- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22a15000    2044       0       0 ----- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22a15000       0       0       0 ----- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22c14000      12       0       0 r---- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22c14000       0       0       0 r---- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22c17000       4       0       0 rw--- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22c17000       0       0       0 rw--- libnss_systemd.so.2
00007f1b22c18000   10240      72      72 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b22c18000       0       0       0 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b23618000   51200    5480    5480 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b23618000       0       0       0 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b26818000   10240     636     636 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b26818000       0       0       0 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b27218000   51200     220     220 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b27218000       0       0       0 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b2a418000      92       4       0 r-x-- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a418000       0       0       0 r-x-- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a42f000    2048       0       0 ----- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a42f000       0       0       0 ----- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a62f000       4       0       0 r---- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a62f000       0       0       0 r---- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a630000       4       0       0 rw--- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a630000       0       0       0 rw--- libresolv-2.27.so
00007f1b2a631000       8       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2a631000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2a633000      20       8       0 r-x-- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a633000       0       0       0 r-x-- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a638000    2048       0       0 ----- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a638000       0       0       0 ----- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a838000       4       0       0 r---- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a838000       0       0       0 r---- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a839000       4       0       0 rw--- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a839000       0       0       0 rw--- libnss_dns-2.27.so
00007f1b2a83a000      44      44       0 r-x-- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2a83a000       0       0       0 r-x-- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2a845000    2044       0       0 ----- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2a845000       0       0       0 ----- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa44000       4       0       0 r---- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa44000       0       0       0 r---- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa45000       4       0       0 rw--- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa45000       0       0       0 rw--- libnss_files-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa46000      24       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2aa46000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2aa4c000      92      48       0 r-x-- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa4c000       0       0       0 r-x-- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa63000    2044       0       0 ----- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2aa63000       0       0       0 ----- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac62000       4       0       0 r---- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac62000       0       0       0 r---- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac63000       4       0       0 rw--- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac63000       0       0       0 rw--- libnsl-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac64000       8       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2ac64000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2ac66000      44      32       0 r-x-- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac66000       0       0       0 r-x-- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac71000    2044       0       0 ----- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ac71000       0       0       0 ----- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae70000       4       0       0 r---- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae70000       0       0       0 r---- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae71000       4       0       0 rw--- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae71000       0       0       0 rw--- libnss_nis-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae72000      32      24       0 r-x-- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae72000       0       0       0 r-x-- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae7a000    2048       0       0 ----- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2ae7a000       0       0       0 ----- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2b07a000       4       0       0 r---- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2b07a000       0       0       0 r---- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2b07b000       4       0       0 rw--- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2b07b000       0       0       0 rw--- libnss_compat-2.27.so
00007f1b2b07c000    1948    1488       0 r-x-- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b07c000       0       0       0 r-x-- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b263000    2048       0       0 ----- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b263000       0       0       0 ----- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b463000      16       8       8 r---- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b463000       0       0       0 r---- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b467000       8       8       8 rw--- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b467000       0       0       0 rw--- libc-2.27.so
00007f1b2b469000      16      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2b469000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2b46d000     112     112       0 r-x-- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b46d000       0       0       0 r-x-- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b489000    2044       0       0 ----- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b489000       0       0       0 ----- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b688000       4       4       4 r---- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b688000       0       0       0 r---- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b689000       4       4       4 rw--- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b689000       0       0       0 rw--- libz.so.1.2.11
00007f1b2b68a000    2148     724       0 r-x-- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2b68a000       0       0       0 r-x-- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2b8a3000    2044       0       0 ----- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2b8a3000       0       0       0 ----- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2baa2000     112      52      52 r---- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2baa2000       0       0       0 r---- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2babe000      48      28      28 rw--- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2babe000       0       0       0 rw--- libcrypto.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2baca000      12       8       8 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2baca000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2bacd000     376     192       0 r-x-- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bacd000       0       0       0 r-x-- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bb2b000    2048       0       0 ----- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bb2b000       0       0       0 ----- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bd2b000      16       8       8 r---- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bd2b000       0       0       0 r---- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bd2f000      24      24      24 rw--- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bd2f000       0       0       0 rw--- libssl.so.1.0.0
00007f1b2bd35000     448     136       0 r-x-- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bd35000       0       0       0 r-x-- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bda5000    2048       0       0 ----- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bda5000       0       0       0 ----- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bfa5000       4       4       4 r---- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bfa5000       0       0       0 r---- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bfa6000       4       0       0 rw--- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bfa6000       0       0       0 rw--- libpcre.so.3.13.3
00007f1b2bfa7000      36      36       0 r-x-- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2bfa7000       0       0       0 r-x-- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2bfb0000    2044       0       0 ----- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2bfb0000       0       0       0 ----- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1af000       4       4       4 r---- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1af000       0       0       0 r---- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1b0000       4       0       0 rw--- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1b0000       0       0       0 rw--- libcrypt-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1b1000     184       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c1b1000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c1df000     104     104       0 r-x-- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1df000       0       0       0 r-x-- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1f9000    2044       0       0 ----- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c1f9000       0       0       0 ----- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c3f8000       4       4       4 r---- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c3f8000       0       0       0 r---- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c3f9000       4       0       0 rw--- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c3f9000       0       0       0 rw--- libpthread-2.27.so
00007f1b2c3fa000      16       4       4 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c3fa000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c3fe000      12       8       0 r-x-- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c3fe000       0       0       0 r-x-- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c401000    2044       0       0 ----- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c401000       0       0       0 ----- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c600000       4       4       4 r---- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c600000       0       0       0 r---- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c601000       4       0       0 rw--- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c601000       0       0       0 rw--- libdl-2.27.so
00007f1b2c602000     156     156       0 r-x-- ld-2.27.so
00007f1b2c602000       0       0       0 r-x-- ld-2.27.so
00007f1b2c7f8000     128      60      60 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b2c7f8000       0       0       0 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b2c818000      28      20      20 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c818000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c827000       4       0       0 rw-s- [aio] (deleted)
00007f1b2c827000       0       0       0 rw-s- [aio] (deleted)
00007f1b2c828000       4       4       4 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b2c828000       0       0       0 rw-s- zero (deleted)
00007f1b2c829000       4       4       4 r---- ld-2.27.so
00007f1b2c829000       0       0       0 r---- ld-2.27.so
00007f1b2c82a000       4       4       4 rw--- ld-2.27.so
00007f1b2c82a000       0       0       0 rw--- ld-2.27.so
00007f1b2c82b000       4       4       4 rw---   [ anon ]
00007f1b2c82b000       0       0       0 rw---   [ anon ]
00007fff6e5c1000     132      16      16 rw---   [ stack ]
00007fff6e5c1000       0       0       0 rw---   [ stack ]
00007fff6e5f1000      12       0       0 r----   [ anon ]
00007fff6e5f1000       0       0       0 r----   [ anon ]
00007fff6e5f4000       8       4       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
00007fff6e5f4000       0       0       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4       0       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       0       0       0 r-x--   [ anon ]
---------------- ------- ------- ------- 
total kB         3319780 3159440 3155760
```

Comment: This memory usage is ~15min after restart. Other servers with the almost the same config and load is using ~400mb.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the Nginx and site configuration. What is the server doing? Serving static files? Do you have any page caches configured in Nginx? Is Nginx somehow running a scripting language with the Nginx process? What version of Nginx is it, and have you tried an update? What is different between this server and other servers? Can you create a new server to replace this one, if it's virtual?

Comment: top 10 mem talkers `ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%mem | head` and `sudo pmap -x ????` with ???? as the pid of process to have detail on per process memory map.

Comment: I guess pmap is not helpful in this case. Nginx is configured with the cache also configuration is big.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the problem was with the upstream server process which is listening on unix socket and not closing connections (plus leaking file descriptors). I guess nginx kept connections and resources related to it and that was the source of memory leak.
I fixed this problem by fixing upstream server as I was the one responsible for this bug :)

Comment: Great that you found it. Can you edit your answer to tell us how you found it, and tell us how you fixed it, in case anyone else has a similar problem in future?

Comment: Can you tell how did you fix it?

Comment: If I remember well upstream server was written in Go and I forgot to close request body `defer r.Body.Close()`. This kept connections open.